# How to create a "stylable" custom control in XAML for Universal Apps?

Tags: custom-controls, winrt-xaml, win-universal-app

I created a custom control:

```cs
internal sealed class FieldControl : Control
{
    public FieldControl()
    {
        this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof (FieldControl);
    }

    public string Text
    {
        get { return (string)this.GetValue(TextProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(TextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string), typeof(FieldControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

with the following style:

```xaml
<Style TargetType="localControls:FieldControl">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="localControls:FieldControl">
                <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

and used it like:

```xaml
<localControls:FieldControl Width="70" Height="70" Text="{Binding}" Background="DarkSlateBlue" Foreground="Cyan"></localControls:FieldControl>
```

Now, this looks okay until I add more properties to set and change at runtime. Hence, I would like to apply a style to `FieldControl`. So, instead of the above, I should be able to do:

```xaml
<localControls:FieldControl Width="70" Height="70" Text="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource State1Style}"></localControls:FieldControl>
```

Where `State1Style` is:

```xaml
<Style x:Key="State1Style" TargetType="localControls:FieldControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSlateBlue"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Cyan"></Setter>
</Style>
```

However, this didn't work for some reason. First, Visual Studio (with ReSharper installed) complains that `State1Style` is not found. Second, when I run the app `FieldControl` has no style applied at all... basically I see nothing on the screen.

I search online and none of the article I found talks about this topic. I appreciate if someone can help me to figure this out.

The ultimate goal is to have a `StyleSelector` which will choose the style at runtime based on the control state.

Answer (score 0):

I've had luck overwriting the template in the style.

```xaml
<Style x:Key="State1Style" TargetType="localControls:FieldControl">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkSlateBlue"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Cyan"></Setter>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="localControls:FieldControl">
                <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                    <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" BorderThickness="1"></Border>
                    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" FontSize="24"></TextBlock>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: What I should write instead of `this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof (FieldControl);` to have `State1Style` as my default style? Or should I define N+1 styles? 1 with no `x:Key` and N for the number of different styles I want my control to have.

Comment: I would define N+1 styles. Is your default style in the generic.xaml?

Comment: have you checked out http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/XAML-user-and-custom-a8a9505e ?

Comment: Yes, this sample code was one of the first I saw. Still, like all other example I saw, none is talking about styling the custom control like we style the built-in ones. For the other question, my style is in some XAML file (`ResourceDictionary`). My controls picks it from there as long as it's not named by `x:Key`.

Comment: Try moving the template into a resource dictionary located in Themes\generic.xaml

Comment: Sorry if this sounded like a dumb question, but I'm sort of lost now :) What should I move to Themes\generic.xaml? The +1, the N or all? And this supposed to help in what part? Or are we talking here about my original attempt (as described in the question)?

Comment: no worries. The default style should be in themes\generic.xaml. In the msdn example you will see the same convention.

Comment: also here is a tutorial which helped me write custom controls for universal apps. http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/99bb20/custom-control-in-windows-8-apps-using-C-Sharp/

Comment: Looks like the only difference between using a style defined in themes\generic.xaml and the one defined some other `ResourceDictionary` is that the former doesn't require manual loading (in App.xaml). Both require a "keyless" style (no `x:Key` defined) with `TargetType` as your control type. I opted for not using themes\generic.xaml because I'm loading the `ResourceDictionary` where I defined my control styles anyway.

Comment: Thank you for following up.